# is it possible to have the desktop on Mac OS X be the same as your home directory?

Tags: macos, mac

GNOME has an option "desktop is home dir" (under Nautilus preferences in gconf-editor).  When this is enabled the folder /home/me/Desktop is not used, instead the files which show up as icons on your desktop as the contents of /home/me.

Is this possible on Mac OS X?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but what if you made `/home/user/Desktop` a symbolic link to `/home/user/`? You would do this by typing the command `ln -s /home/user/Desktop /home/user/`.

I have no idea if that will work... You'll probably have to remove the contents of `/Desktop` folder first before creating the link - this way you don't accidentally lose anything already on your desktop.

If that doesn't work, I'm not sure how you would do this...

Good luck!

Comment: Don't have my Macbook with me so I'll try tonight, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This may work, but note that Mac OS X directory structure is different from Linux. `~` is `/Users/user`.

Comment: Good catch Paul! I haven't used a Mac in almost 2 years - I forget their structure is a little different! +1

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work.  Seems like OS X does more than just look for /Users/me/Desktop.  If you move or rename that folder its contents are still shown on your desktop.  The symlink didn't seem to affect that.